# What does it mean if a professor asks you to draft his reference letter for you?

Tags: phd, application, recommendation-letter

This question is, honestly speaking, probably somewhat opinion-based, but I still want to give a shot.

A professor acceded to my invitation of writing a reference letter for me. Nevertheless, unlike the other professors who also acceded to write a reference letter for me, he asked me to draft it on my own. Originally I did not feel anything "wrong", and I just felt embarrassed to recommend myself. But yesterday a friend told me that a professor would ask you to write her reference letter for you when she does not actually think that you are "worthy" enough for her to write you one on her own.

What is the probability that such viewpoint is true? Any opinion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it acceptable to write a reference letter for yourself?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-reference-letter-for-yourself)

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: Thanks for your information :) I have taken a quick overview on the question with finding almost nothing solving my problem here. Therefore, I am afraid I will insist on soliciting opinions!

Comment: @JukkaSuomela that question is asking "is it ethical", this question is asking "what does it mean". I think they are related, but not duplicate.

Comment: With all due respect to your friend, I think they're very wrong and I highly recommend that you don't take their advice/point of view on the mater. By saying what they said, your friend sound like that child in primary school who ran around and told us that you can get pregnant by kissing somebody. Personally, I'd think less of somebody (intellectually) if they believe such things.

Comment: @Adnan That's uncalled for (and starting with "with all due respect) does not make your comment less insulting.

Comment: @Adnan: It is fine :) Thank you for your encouragement! I totally understand your point, and I won't in any sense take it personal.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer: Back in the day I asked a particular professor for a letter of recommendation. I know the professor liked me personally and also that I was one of their best, if not the very best, students. He asked me to draft it on my own "because your English is probably better than mine" -- a silly-sounding reason if there ever was one. My point: don't worry. :-)

Comment: When I finished up a multi-year run as a contractor many years ago, the firm I was with insisted I ask the client for a letter of recommendation. When I approached the client manager he said, "Write your own letter and I'll sign it", which I did, but upon reading it he said, "*This* is all you can say about yourself?!? Give me five minutes", took my draft, and converted it from my "Bob is a competent professional" to "Bob is the most totally effing amazing developer EVER!". (I was, frankly, embarrassed). Translation: the prof is inviting you to make you look good. Go for it.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Your story does not take place in an academic context.  This OP is speaking about letters for graduate school.  In this context leaving the student to write their own letter is doing them no favors.

Comment: To risk an analogy: it is as if you want to start a modelling career, you go to a professional photographer for a headshot, and he says: "Why don't you take the picture yourself, give me the film, and I'll touch it up in the darkroom if that turns out to be necessary.  I want you to make yourself look good!" Simply writing that the OP is really effing good is not what is called for.  Professional familiarity with academia and letter writing skills are called for.

Comment: It means your professor is shirking their duties.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

For me, it means two things:

- I am really busy
- I don't know anything about the job you're applying to and what you want to emphasize about yourself

If the first draft you write is something I can't sign, I'll edit it or I won't sign it. If it's not braggy enough, I might add some emphasis. But metaphorically handing me a piece of blank paper and asking me to recommend you is actually asking me to put in quite a lot of work. Do these people you're applying to value initiative? Creativity? Willingness to work long hard hours? Cheerfullness? A driven nature? A gentle spirit? Is the fact you write great software relevant to them? How about your careful bench work? For all I know you want to do less of one thing and more of another. So now I need to ask you a zillion questions about what you want to emphasize, and maybe go research the job too, and then ask you if what I've written is ok - frankly, it's **way easier** to ask you to write the first draft. And some days, I take the easy route.

It does **not** mean:

- I intend to sign words I didn't write. I will write the final draft
- It's ok for you to make up strengths you don't have
- You'll know what I send in the end
- I can't write a simple letter without help from a student.

Your first draft doesn't even have to be a letter, it can be point form. But tell me you're choosing me as a reference so I can confirm your amazing Xness, Yabilty and Zation. If I can, I will.

By the way, I wish I could find the idiot who started the theory that it means I don't think well of you and want you to retract your request. Several students have retracted their requests after I asked for a first draft, and that's a shame, because I would have cheerfully signed a glowing recommendation for them. I just didn't have time to write it all from scratch myself.

Comment: Hurrah!  While I don't ask students to write draft letters, I do ask them to send me an email detailing why they're particularly qualified for the school or position for which I'm writing a recommendation.  Almost half of them never "get around" to doing that.  Rather than being disappointed, I consider that I've just learned something about the student that might have influenced my recommendation.  For those who may care, here is what I tell students: http://bbrown.spsu.edu/recommendations/index.html

Comment: +1 for "what you want to emphasize about yourself" for the particular position you're applying for.

Comment: @BobBrown very nice!

Comment: -1 for suggesting that there is nothing wrong with asking the student to write the first draft.

Comment: @KateGregory:  Thanks!  Everyone should feel free to borrow any part of that, or all of it, that may look useful.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft there *is* nothing wrong with asking the student to write the first draft - and it's just as okay to simply refuse to write any letter because you don't have the time for it. Unless you have a close collaboration relationship, you don't owe a letter-writing service to everyone who happened to be in a class you taught.

Comment: To me, Bob's approach seems much more ethical than actually asking the student to write a draft of the letter, while still accomplishing the goal of the referrer knowing what the student is applying for (and, thus, what relevant information should be included.)

Comment: @Peteris That depends on several factors. In most of academia, letters of recommendation are supposed to be confidential and never sen by the student at all, let alone let the student themselves choose the overall structure of the letter.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Those things aren't in conflict. You can ask the student to draft the letter, but that doesn't mean they get to see what you eventually send in.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft would you mind posting an answer detailing what you thinking is wrong with it? I'd be curious to know.

Comment: @djechlin The answer by Pete Clark at http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-reference-letter-for-yourself already expresses this way better than I could.

Comment: One criticism here is this assumes the student can write an ideal letter. I am completely positive I could not have written as effective a letter ("Dan is really really smurrttt") as my professors, who know what rec letters are supposed to demonstrate and how to build a case within them, and in many cases directly know the people they are persuading.

Comment: It seems you've missed that the OP is asking about **letters of recommendation for PhD programs**.  Someone who does not understand the specific format and requirements of such a letter far better than any undergraduate applicant would be a bad choice as a letter writer.  The "cheerful signing" you endorse could be viewed as an instance of academic dishonesty on at many American universities.  It may be that you do not view it that way yourself, but it could jeopardize the student's future nevertheless.  Since this is the accepted answer, I wanted to inform the OP about this.

Comment: I find in your answer a great deal of equivocation on the key issue of whether and how much the student's "first draft" will appear in the letter you write.  You seem to know better than to fully admit that you will do this but strongly hint that you do so in certain cases.  "Your first draft doesn't even have to be a letter, it can be point form."  As others have said, it would be **so much better** if you solicited information rather than a draft of a letter.  If you would actually be equally happy with this, please consider revising your answer.

Comment: Students vary. Some write clearly and some don't. When I am asked for a favor, and I'm busy, I may ask the asker to do some of the work, which they will do to varying degrees. The concept that this is somehow plagiarism is ridiculous and I am not going to discuss that any further. It's a letter, not a paper or a book. I sign it because it is from me and the contents accurately represent my opinion.

Comment: Placing students in PhD programs is not a "favor"; it is part of what professors get paid to do.  Moreover it is not a matter of clear writing: if you have not seen such letters before, you simply cannot write them so as to be competitive with letters written by those who have this experience and expertise.  A draft written by a student would be no help to an appropriate letter.  At least, this is my experience after spending four years on graduate admissions in the math PhD program at UGA.  If you have specific contrary experience, I would be very interested to hear it.

Comment: By that theory nobody could ever write a first such letter. The student isn't drafting it because I don't know how to recommend people, but to let me know what skills they believe are important for this position they want to be recommended for. You believe a full time prof will know that better than the student, and you might be right (depending on what the student is applying to.) But you might also be wrong, and some profs are not full time or are new.

Comment: Also, If US PhD programs have some secret scheme where perfect wording on recommendation letters by members of the club who know the trick are the key to getting in, well fine. But that does not mean the entire world of recommendation letters fits that pattern, or that non-US non-full-time profs are somehow cheating or unethical because they don't take your example into account when doing someone a favour.

Comment: @KateGregory: I heartily agree that the entire world of recommendation letters is a vast one.  The OP is applying to STEM PhD programs in the US.  You will not learn what skills are relevant for that by reading a student's draft letter.  Your talk of "secret schemes" seems unhelpful: I have both placed and admitted students in exactly the type of PhD programs he is applying for.  I am trying to provide advice which is specifically targeted to him.  As I said, if you have relevant experience I would be very interested to hear it.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with Pete L. Clark. Writing letters of recommendation is part of the job. It isn't something an undergraduate student can do competently. A professor who does not take these letters very seriously and invest an appropriate amount of time into them is simply throwing his or her students under the bus.

Comment: _I intend to sign words I didn't write._ — In my experience, this is **exactly** what such a request means.

Comment: I have had professors ask for a specific "brag list" (in bullet-point form), or a personal statement, or a transcript. The first of these can provide the benefits of the "you write this" approach without the significant aforementioned drawbacks.

Comment: @shane But how is editing a draft of a student not taking these letters seriously? Of course an undergrad can't do it competently which means the editing will not be minor. Draft or not, the final result is going to be pretty much the same but with a draft it's simply more efficient not necessarily more effective

Comment: Kate Gregory, help please? [Assuming ethical, how do SOLICITED recommendation letter drafts work if the forms are released only after the rest of the application?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97141/)

Comment: @JackBauer Because writing letters is part of the job. It’d be more “efficient” from the profs point of view to have students ‘draft’ the grades on the papers, and ‘draft’ the lectures too. But the point is that doing those things isn’t the students’ job; it’s the prof’s. A good letter is a clear, concise, objective appraisal of the candidates strengths and weaknesses that communicates the salient information in the right way to professional colleagues. I wouldn’t expect a student to be able to produce even a draft of such a letter.

Comment: @KateGregory: I don't mean to be rude, but are you writing this from prior experience as a manager, or as a professor? I've read countless excellent responses from you on Workplace.SE based on your experiences as a manager, but this is the first one I've seen on Academia.SE, and the contrast I'm seeing with the responses of other professors made me wonder whether this is what you have actually previously done yourself as a professor. This is important as my understanding of the situation is that the consensus is that those who have not been in this position do not really know what it like.

Comment: Yes, I was an adjunct for many years and was asked to write reference letters for students in that capacity. Things are one way at large technical universities that are providing, say, grad students to other important technical universities, and another way at small universities where people are applying for jobs or scholarships. I am aware some other answers disagree, but that doesn't make this answer wrong for the scenarios I was in.

Answer (score 50):

At this point I feel I should leave an answer which records a differing opinion.

First, let me provide context.  My advice is for students applying the STEM PhD programs in the United States (like the OP).  I was admitted to the top three math PhD programs in the United States and graduated from one of them in 2003.  Since 2006 I have been tenured-track at UGA; I am now a tenured associate professor.  I spent four years on the Graduate Committee reading applications, and though I am now on a different committee, because I am co-PI on a large NSF grant I read a stack of applications last year and will probably continue to do so for several years to come.  I have also read thousands of academic recommendation letters for faculty positions.  (This is, unfortunately for me, not an exaggeration.)

The accepted answer gives what I think is not good advice for the OP's situation.  I think it might be good advice for non-academic recommendation letters, and I suspect that it was in fact not written to be targeted at PhD applications.  Going over the entire answer point-by-point feels unnecessarily confrontational, but let me differ in some key points, all of which I think could lead a student astray.

- Most of the best recommendation letters for STEM PhD programs in the US are written by those who have substantial experience in this area.  In my field of mathematics, a letter written by someone who does not have a PhD in mathematics or a closely related field is likely to be simply skipped over.  (I have learned on this site that in some other STEM fields, good letters can be written by those who have substantial industrial experience.  But such people still have to have a lot of experience with PhDs in the relevant fields.)  The best letters are written by those who have faculty experience as well, have seen many academic recommendation letters, and who are known by the faculty doing admissions, at least by reputation.

Is this description somewhat elitist and exclusionary of younger, non-tenure track and liberal arts faculty?  Yes, it is.  But it is also honest.  If we get a letter from a small liberal arts college that says "Ms. X is the best student I have ever seen" and then doesn't display a familiarity with the type of students that succeed in programs like ours, it's hard to know what to make of it.  If the recommender is not an active researcher: well, that's just not as good as someone whose name we all know and trust.  How could it be?

In a comment it was suggested that the above situation is impossible because everyone starts out with less experience than the above.  Most letters we get are not written by people who are just starting out.  If you spend a few years in a faculty position you'll see a deluge of academic recommendation letters and absorb the format.  If you are a *very* junior person who is nevertheless a good choice to write a letter (which certainly does happen), you should get help and advice from someone more experienced.  You should not rely on someone who is much less experienced, and still less on an undergraduate, and yet less on that undergraduate for whom you are writing.

- Any reasonably good letter contains components that almost no student could write. For instance such letters should **include information about the credentials and experience of the writer**, enough to explain why their endorsement of the student is to be relied upon.  Such letters should **compare the student generally to other students in the recommender's program, to the generic student in the target PhD program, and ideally to past specific students that the writer and the reader will both know**.  Even the one in a million student who has preternatural access to this information cannot give it: it has to come from writer, in the writer's voice.

There is plenty of room in such an application for a student to provide information about her strengths, goals and interests.  A good faculty letter makes contact with that student information and reinforces it, but such information does not form nearly enough of a letter for it to make sense for a student to write it up as though it could be the basis of the faculty letter: at best, doing this would waste everyone's time, not save it.

- Writing academic letters is not a "favor": it is part of what faculty are paid to do.  More precisely, it is part of what permanent, full-time faculty are paid to do.  I've spent about eight hours over the last few days writing letters for current and former UGA math department personnel, and I will spend at least that much time on the task in the next few weeks.  I spend so much time on these tasks because (i) it's important -- the difference between an effective letter and ineffective one may play out as a difference in some young person's life; and (ii) I have a stake in it as well: when one of our undergraduates goes to a top ten PhD program or one of our PhD students gets an NSF postdoc, my entire department benefits and in so doing **I benefit**.   If I were a temporary, adjunct or part-time faculty member, I strongly suspect that I would not feel the same way, and I certainly would not expect such a faculty member to devote such time and effort.  Someone who thinks of recommendation letters as a favor is someone you don't want to write for you and, I feel, someone who shouldn't have to. Also, **no one** is required to write a letter for any given student: if you feel like you can't write an effective letter, say so and don't do it.
- A letter which is written first by a student and then touched up by the faculty signee is a potentially serious academic honesty situation.  I have spoken about this at length elsewhere on this site.  I respect that some others do not feel this way and that in many situations there is nothing immoral or suboptimal going on here.  However you need to know that many -- I suspect most -- American academics share my qualms.  Even the fact that the student must not see the letter is regarded as sacrosanct by many.  I am very dismayed when people try to say that they are not *really* just signing their students' letters -- or only if they "actually endorse everything that is written"!! -- but are just getting this writing sample as step one of a final product that is not in any way problematic.  To that I say: if you know how to write a reasonable specimen of an academic letter you will know that a "student draft" is at best helpful only as a source of information about the student, so what is being gained by not just asking for the information outside of a letter format?  By soliciting a student draft **you are inviting the student to be complicit in a possible academic dishonesty whose final outcome is unknown to them**.  If later in their graduate career it comes up that they *think* they wrote their own letter it could still go or at least look very badly for them, even if it turns out that nothing so terrible actually transpired.  Then there are the deceptive habits you are implicitly conveying to the student as being part of normal academic business.  If you don't think you are teaching the student to be deceptive, ask yourself this: would you be willing to submit a letter that was signed jointly by you and the student, or even in which it is explicitly mentioned that it was written based on an early draft of the student?  If you are not willing to put that in the letter, then yes, you are being unethically deceptive and encouraging the student to do the same.  If on the other hand you are willing to put that in the letter: **please try it**, and see what happens.  I think you'll get some interesting feedback.

Comment: Adding my $0.02. I think Pete L. Clark is absolutely on point for Philosophy in the US as well.

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer. I was considering writing something along these lines, but I was hoping you would come along and do it instead, as you are better positioned to write it (and to write it better than I could have).

Comment: While I agree with everything in your post I don't believe the effectiveness of the letter and the ethics of this practice were part of OPs question. He asked whether being asked to draft his own recommendation letter meant that the professor cared less or didn't want him to succeed. Which is why I said it probably wasn't the case because they have more direct ways to get in your way than ask you to draft your own letter. The accepted answer agrees with my statement, but goes on further to say that they engage in that practice. Now if you believe that is unethical, I agree, but it's off topic.

Comment: @Salim: When one believes an answer contains inaccurate information, it is reasonable to leave an answer discussing it.  This is true on any SE site.  It seems especially pertinent on advice-type sites like ours.  In this case the gist of my answer -- namely, when someone asks you to write your own letter, whether they think well or ill of you, you would be most unwise to take them up on it -- does not answer the exact question the OP asked, but it is obviously relevant to anyone who is in the OP's situation.  (I have no problem with your answer, by the way. No one does: it stands at +7/-0.)

Comment: 90% of the faculty in my top institution is unethical because they all asked me to draft the letter for them.

Comment: @user10694: Sorry, I don't believe you asked 90% of the faculty at your institution for letters.  But if you want to provide the name of your institution, I can look into the prevalence of the practice there.

Comment: This answer is a thing of beauty.  Thank you for demanding excellence and clearly stating what the responsibilities of the folks involved are.

Comment: "By soliciting a student draft you are inviting the student to be complicit in a possible academic dishonesty whose final outcome is unknown to them" What precisely is considered a "draft" ? For example if I fill in the parts of the forms for the professors such as university address or my application number is the part of a "draft" ?

Comment: Re "I don't know anything about the job you're applying to and what you want to emphasize about yourself". Case 1. it is ethical to give professor info about job or what i want to emphasize about myself: How do I communicate this w/o making a "draft" ? Case 2. Otherwise: Why?

Comment: @JackBauer: Something that has the format of a letter and could be signed and sent "if the professor agrees with everything you wrote" is the most problematic kind of draft.  In general you should not send along text that evaluates yourself or argues for admitting yourself.  It is perfectly fine to send along factual *information*.  Filling out routine factual information in online forms is not inherently unethical, but American admissions officials would still view it with some concern: if you have access to the online form, how do we know you're not filling out other parts of it?

Comment: What would you advise a student's course of action when asked to draft his own reference letter by a professor?

Comment: I'd argue that asking for bullet points rather than a first draft is much better (1) it reduces any temptation for the faculty member to not use their own voice while still providing them useful info for the letter and (2) even if the faculty member commits academic dishonesty and copy-pastes the bullet points, at least the student cannot reasonably be found to be complicit, because no-one could reasonably interpret a list of bullet points as an attempt to draft the letter.

Answer (score 9):

One reason that often occurs, is that the person is not familiar with your accomplishments and would need a quick refresher by having you draft the letter, since they are usually supposed to illustrate with examples as they list your qualities. Another reason is that certain scholarship and university applications want these letters to have a specific format and include specific details about your potential as a researcher. Your reference may just be too busy to study up on the requirements.

If they didn't think you were worthy of admission for a PhD program they could just write a letter themselves saying "don't accept this guy, he is a terrible incompetent jerk", without you ever finding out about it, rather than ask you to draft it first.

Comment: Ah thanks. But is there really possible an adult who acceded to write a reference letter with contents full of derogatory words?

Comment: Having been on admissions and search committees, negative letters are thankfully rare but they do exist.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer I heard one "story" to this end: a person (computer science), applied to a PhD position and among other people, asked her supervisor to write a letter. The letters were anonymous, but after she got accepted, her new prof / department told her: _"We decided to accept you_ despite _your supervisor's letter"_

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the professor wants the student to confirm what they already know about them.  It could be the professor is attempting to help the student grow by having them recognize their own achievements.  Perhaps the student is not one to assert themselves and this is an attempt to bring out this trait.
In an academic environment learning includes learning about yourself as well as content.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common for an advisor to ask his student to write the letter. I have seen that several times. The reasons are that the advisor is generally very busy and that you are generally the person that knows best what should be written for the job that you are applying. Moreover, if you ask several recommendation letters (let say from 3 persons), you can decide what each of them will say and avoid redundancy between the letters if you write them. Of course, the advisor will then read what you wrote and if he don't agree he will modify it.