# Having problem in getting LOR for higher study because of my corrupted undergrad thesis supervisor

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, masters, recommendation-letter

I am an engineering graduate in Bangladesh. During my undergrad thesis, my supervisor took students for working on a topic that was for the first time in our department but he didn't help any of his thesis groups. Every year he takes thesis group for money but never ever teach or help any of the students about respective research work. Students somehow spend the year & gets out of the university. If somebody can do something better, he forces the student to include his name in the research paper as author though he has not helped in any aspect.

Since the beginning, my thesis group requested him a lot to teach & help to do our research work. He just wasted our time by telling repeatedly "contact me next week" & at the end of the year he said: "I can't help, whatever you can do submit it soon".

He didn't take a single tutorial class on research topic but forced us to submit thesis. We didn’t know what to do, how to do, we had not worked on research project before, we were newbie & he was destroying our future...

At last all the groups (12 students in total) passed the course submitting a simple copy-paste project. We complained against him to the Head of the Department since he betrayed 12 students; HOD didn't take any corrective action. That corrupted professor got angry against us.

I've become very much frustrated because I spent 1,600,000 BDT (around $19K USD) for undergrad tuition fees, didn't learn about doing research & the outcome is such a miserable condition.

How can I, from whom can I collect LOR for my higher studies in USA/Canada? What should I do? I've become utterly clueless.

Comment: Are there other professors who know your work and can speak to your skills?

Comment: Due to COVID19 my country banned physical classes since last 16 months & it's going on till now. I had to do online zoom class throughout my entire final year, teachers just appeared online, took the class & left. We didn't get any opportunity  working with other professors because all labs are normally taken by newly recruited lecturers. Professors are just responsible to take theoretical classes & to interact with his thesis groups only.

Comment: During my last semester, I attended a non-credit course offered by an associate professor of another university. Fortunately, I achieved certification of excellence from him. But it's non-credit course offered by another university faculty, not of my own.

Comment: Very closely related: [Because of past conflicts, I don't believe my advisor will write me a good LOR for postdoc positions. What should I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55393/because-of-past-conflicts-i-dont-believe-my-advisor-will-write-me-a-good-lor-f); see also [How can I get a reference letter if I was never close to any professors?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82532) and [If I cannot get sufficient recommendation letters, what can I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20323)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are in a bad place, but you have to make the best use of the resources that you have available. I don't think that using a professor from a different institution is necessarily bad, provided that they can honestly predict your future success.

You might also talk to the Head and see if there is something they can suggest. They have a responsibility to work with you even if they haven't been very supportive in the past. But your success or lack of it reflects on them as well.