# Asked to write a Letter of Recommendation about myself

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

I am a student applying to a graduate program. Part of the application requires submitting some letters of recommendation.

I asked a former professor whose class I enjoyed, but she surprisingly asked that I write one myself, send it to her, and she would sign and submit it. This feels disingenuous at best and fraudulent at worst.

Is this a common practice, or should I seek letters elsewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable to write a reference letter for yourself?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-reference-letter-for-yourself)

Comment: Thinking of it as a draft that they'll review before signing can help.