# What to do when an advisor asks you to draft your recommendation?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, advisor

A friend of mine is applying to graduate schools, and his research advisor asked him to write the recommendation and he would sign it as his own.

It doesn't seem possible for my friend to write a genuine letter about himself. I would think admissions committees would be able to spot it right away.

He has a very strong application otherwise, with a first author publication in a reputable journal (STEM field) with the very same advisor as an undergraduate!

Would you write the letter yourself? Would you get a recommendation from someone else? Could this be a deal breaker for his application?

Comment: Also see [Points to remember when having to write recommendation letter yourself](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/points-to-remember-when-having-to-write-recommendation-letter-yourself)